# Receive push notification with sound

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, react-native

I have a react-native app which can receive push notifications with the react-native-gcm-android package. I want to play a sound (wether default or a custom) when I receive a push.

I tried some variations of my gcm payload, but none of the versions plays something:

```
dataPayload = {
    'title': 'Stackoverflow',
    'badge': 'Increment',
    'alert': alert,
    'notification': {
      'subject': 'Stackoverflow',
      'message': 'Some message',
      'sound': 'default'
    }
}

dataPayload = {
    'title': 'Stackoverflow',
    'badge': 'Increment',
    'alert': 'Some text',
    'notification': {
      'subject': 'Stackoverflow',
      'message': 'Some message',
      'sound': 'android.resource://com.mypackagename.myapp/sound.mp3'
    }
}

dataPayload = {
    'title': 'Stackoverflow',
    'badge': 'Increment',
    'alert': 'Some text',
    'notification': {
      'subject': 'Stackoverflow',
      'message': 'Some message',
      'sound': true
    }
}
```

The sound.mp3 file is located under `android/app/src/res/`

Comment: You should put your mp3 file inside raw folder. Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `react-native-push-notification`, [a fix can be found here](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/pull/225)

Answer (score -2):

sound file should be in /res/raw 
as [doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table2) says

Comment: Sound file can be used from assets too!

Comment: Android sound files must reside in /res/raw/, this line is in docs i menthoned above.